# Dropdown Menu doesn't show all links and can't change css social media icons color

Tags: html, css

First the Header doesn't let the Dropdown Menu to show all links, How to fix this issue ?
Second I have add css link to show social media icons and I set color to each on of them, But after adding link  to each one of them they appear as a normal visited link  color, I tried to add color: none; and text-decoration: none; without success, Here is the code But it doesn't show the social media icons I don't know why.
Thanks.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  plusSlides(1)
}, 4000);
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
}
header li {
  float: left;
}
header li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header li a:hover:not(.activelink) {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}
header .activelink {
  background-color: #02b8dd;
}
header .links {
  margin-top: 35px;
}
header .logo {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
figcaption {
  font-size: 21px;
}
footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
footer p {
  text-align: center;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 200px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: none;
  padding: 20px 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.active:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
.dropbtn {
  margin-top: 35px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #02b8dd;
}
.fa:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook-official {
  color: #3b5998;
}
.fa-facebook-official:hover {
  color: #3b5998;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #55acee;
}
.fa-twitter-square:hover {
  color: #55acee;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.fa-youtube-square {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.fa-youtube-square:hover {
  color: #bb0000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a class="links logo" href="index.html">
          <img src="images/logo.png" />
          <figcaption>Lorem ipsum</figcaption>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links activelink" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="games.html">link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content droplink">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
            <a href="#">link 4</a>
            <a href="#">link 5</a>
            <a href="#">link 6</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="#">link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="#">link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="#">link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right"><a class="links " href="#">link 5</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right"><a class="links " href="#">link 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li style="font-size:48px;color:#3b5998">
        <a class="fa fa-facebook-official" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
      </li>

      <li style="font-size:48px;color:#1da1f2">
        <a class="fa fa-twitter-square" href="https://twitter.com/"></a>
      </li>

      <li style="font-size:48px;color:red">
        <a class="fa fa-youtube-square" href="https://www.youtube.com/">
        </a>

        <li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">

        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://www.fullhdwpp.com/wp-content/uploads/daisy-wallpaper-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </a>
        <div class="text">1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">

        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://www.fullhdwpp.com/wp-content/uploads/Blue-Leaves-in-Depth-of-Field-4_www.FullHDWpp.com_.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </a>
        <div class="text">2</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">

        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/purple_flower_fractal_81490_1920x1080.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </a>
        <div class="text">3</div>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="clear">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from `<ul>` and add make it a flex container using `display: flex;`.

And you have implemented the `fontawesome` icons in your CSS, which is a wrong way of doing it. I've included it inside the HTML section. And added the color according to the social media icons as well.

Have a look at the working snippet below (*use full screen mode*):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  plusSlides(1)
}, 4000);
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
}

header li {
  float: left;
}

header li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header li a:hover:not(.activelink) {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

header .activelink {
  background-color: #02b8dd;
}

header .links {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

header .logo {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 21px;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 200px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: none;
  padding: 20px 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.active:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.dropbtn {
  margin-top: 35px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #02b8dd;
}

.fa:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-facebook-official {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-facebook-official:hover {
  color: #3b5998;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #55acee;
}

.fa-twitter-square:hover {
  color: #55acee;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.fa-youtube-square {
  color: #bb0000;
}

.fa-youtube-square:hover {
  color: #bb0000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}

.dropdown-content.droplink {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a class="links logo" href="index.html">
          <img src="images/logo.png" />
          <figcaption>Lorem ipsum</figcaption>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links activelink" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="games.html">link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content droplink">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
            <a href="#">link 4</a>
            <a href="#">link 5</a>
            <a href="#">link 6</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="#">link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="#">link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="links " href="#">link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right"><a class="links " href="#">link 5</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right"><a class="links " href="#">link 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li style="font-size:48px;color:#3b5998">
        <a class="fa fa-facebook-official" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
      </li>

      <li style="font-size:48px;color:#1da1f2">
        <a class="fa fa-twitter-square" href="https://twitter.com/"></a>
      </li>

      <li style="font-size:48px;color:red">
        <a class="fa fa-youtube-square" href="https://www.youtube.com/">
        </a>

        <li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section>

    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">

        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://www.fullhdwpp.com/wp-content/uploads/daisy-wallpaper-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </a>
        <div class="text">1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">

        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://www.fullhdwpp.com/wp-content/uploads/Blue-Leaves-in-Depth-of-Field-4_www.FullHDWpp.com_.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </a>
        <div class="text">2</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">

        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/purple_flower_fractal_81490_1920x1080.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </a>
        <div class="text">3</div>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="clear">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot!
 I have a new issue after adding a <section> which it contain a slideshow images, The dropdown menu links is under the slideshow.

Comment: @EgyMMM Can you show me the code, or update you snippet?

Comment: Sorry didn't know I have to mention you to get notify @SauravRastogi

Comment: @EgyMMM Updated my answer. Just give `z-index: 1` to `.dropdown-content.droplink`. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks A lot!,
I just have a side question I downloaded `font-awesome.min.css` and add 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css"> but it doesn't show the icons and if I add 'css/font-awesome.min.css' it show a weird symbols, I download the css file so I can open the page in other pc where there is no internet. @SauravRastogi

Comment: @EgyMMM First of all put your fontawesome `<link>` tag to the HTML part in the snippet (as I've done), currently its inside the CSS part of the snippet. Secondly download the fontawesome files from http://fontawesome.io website and then give relative path to it inside your link tag to make it work offline. Also if this answer helped you don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help

Comment: @EgyMMM Its my pleasure!